# GPSD logs on ubuntu (syslog)

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, gps

I am debugging gpsd in ubuntu. gpsd uses syslog. However I don't know where the log is getting stored. Any clues please?

Comment: See /var/log/syslog. You can save yourself time and effort by asking the 'Search' box at the top of every AskUbuntu page. Many gpsd questions have already been answered.

Comment: Read `man rsyslog.conf;man rsyslogd`, and look at `/etc/rsyslog.conf`